# Xtend is not recognizing my variable

Tags: xtext

I wrote the following code in xtend,

```
 override complete_def_slotted_exemplar(EObject model, RuleCall ruleCall, ContentAssistContext context, ICompletionProposalAcceptor acceptor) {
  super.complete_def_slotted_exemplar(model, ruleCall, context, acceptor)
  acceptor.accept(createCompletionProposal("_pragma(classify_level= basic, topic={}, usage={})\ndef_slotted_exemplar(:exemplar_name,\n
 ## 
 ## 
 ##
 {

 },\n{ }\t)\n$","def_slotted_exemplar",null,context));
 }
```

Initially it is showing in the list, but when I tried to type def, it's not showing in the list.

Comment: but when i written code as with dot(.) before def_slotted_exemplar, it is showing the list but dot get appended which is wrong.                   override complete_def_slotted_exemplar(EObject model, RuleCall ruleCall, ContentAssistContext context, ICompletionProposalAcceptor acceptor) {
  super.complete_def_slotted_exemplar(model, ruleCall, context, acceptor)
  acceptor.accept(createCompletionProposal("_pragma(classify_level= basic, topic={}, usage={})\ndef_slotted_exemplar(:exemplar_name,\n
 ## 
 ## 
 ##
 {

 },\n{ }\t)\n$","def_slotted_exemplar",null,context));
 } v v b

Comment: can you share a minimal reproducing grammar and sample model as well. and you might debug PrefixMatcher

Comment: what add. strikes me is that the proposal starts with `_pragma` but the method is called `complete_def_slotted_exemplar`

Comment: This is my model                                                                               
  Model:
  (types+=Type)*;

 Type:
 
def_slotted_exemplar|Method|BLOCK|PRAGMA|THISTHREAD|PROC|GlobalVar|PACKAGE|define_slot_access|define_shared_constant|define_shared_variable
 |def_property|define_property|define_property_signature|'$'|';'|CONDTION|SMALLWORDREGISTRATION
 //'.'
 
  ;
 Exemplar:
  'def_slotted_exemplar'
 ;
 def_slotted_exemplar: 
   Exemplar  ('('':'name=ID )
     ',');

Comment: please edit your question